# Shopware 5 compatible version of MariaDB

Tags: shopware, shopware5

The hosting partner of many of our customers is deactivating MariaDB < 10.3. Now I try to find out from which Shopware 5 version it is compatible with MariaDb 10.3. Checked change logs and documentation, but the only thing I find is that Shopware 6 requires 10.3 atleast. Is there some reliable source for this information?

See also

Announcment (german): https://timmehosting.de/blog/abschaltung-alter-php-und-mariadb-versionen-ab-dem-30092022

Translated to english: https://timmehosting-de.translate.goog/blog/abschaltung-alter-php-und-mariadb-versionen-ab-dem-30092022?_x_tr_sl=de&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp

Comment: I would say the Shopware Support ;-)

Comment: I know I'm waiting for them to reply here ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got feedback from some Shopware developer.

> I can't give you a 100% certanty. However we had no isses with 10.3.x with 5.5.x Shops. With older version we had huge issues that the handling in MariaDB for NULL values changed a bit and so the doctrine version used in 5.4 and before caused the database values to be no longer NULL but the string "NULL" which caused some sideffects obviously